# How to crawl xml files in sharepoint 2010 search

Tags: search

I have a scenario where we have to crawl external website which is having bulks of xml files in a location we need to crawl them to show up in our search results .when we try to do that it is hsoing the results in .xml fashion. but we need the results to be in wording form .For example if we are seraching for '**Japan**' we are getting the results as **'1980-120.xml'** but we need to get as '**japan**' or related to it.please any suggestion how to resolve it or any better approaches to crawl external websites.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If "**1980-120.xml**" is the name of the file, that's what you're going to get in your search results. If you want the displayed title text to be "**japan**" you will need to rename the file or customize your search results page to implement your custom business logic.

See [Customizing the SharePoint 2010 Search User Experience](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/customizing-sharepoint-2010-search-user-experience) for a nice tutorial on how to do this from WROX. I'd also recommend getting the book the tutorial is from. I've found the copy on my desk pretty handy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response rjcup3.I have quick question can you sugest anyother way to crawl external website to get the results in sharepoint search form that external site..